# Setting global properties by calling imported javascript functions in QML

Tags: javascript, qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I use the [Universal style](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-universal.html) for my QtQuick app and I want to provide a [ColorDialog](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-dialogs-colordialog.html) for adjusting the accent color.

I have something like this:

```
ColorDialog {
    id: accChooser
    title: "Please choose a color"
        onAccepted: {
            setGlobalAccentColor(accChooser.color) 
        }
}
```

*Note that I cannot simply write `Universal.accent=...` inside a child item because it has no effect on the parent.See [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-universal.html#universal-accent-attached-prop).

and this function:

```
function setGlobalAccentColor(accentColor){
    Universal.accent = accentColor
}
```

It works when the function `setGlobalAccentColor` is defined within the same QML file as `accChooser`,but if I define that function inside an external JS file (say `helpers.js`) and import it via:

```
import "helpers.js" as JSHelpers
```

and use it this way:

```
ColorDialog{
...
    JSHelpers.setGlobalAccentColor(colorDialog.color)
...
}
```

it doesn't work.There's no specific error or warning message in the output of the app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

May be it is required to import the universal style in the javascript file.

The documentation [universal style](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-universal.html) says below (look in dependency section)

> The Universal style must be separately imported to gain access to the
> attributes that are specific to the Universal style

You can try [importing](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-imports.html) as said below into your javascript (helpers.js) file.

```
.import QtQuick.Controls.Universal 2.12 as JsUniversal
```

And then try accessing (like example: `JsUniversal.accent`..).

Comment: Hi @Paven.Sadly it doesn't work.In the [link](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-imports.html#imports-within-javascript-resources) you provided it also has been mentioned that ```A script without imports will inherit imports from the QML document which imported it``` for backward compatibility.So another import in the JS file doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

> Note that I cannot simply write Universal.accent=... inside a child item because it has no effect on the parent.See this.

While setting it to the child won't affect your whole application, you can set it directly to the whole window.

```
Window.window.Universal.accent = accentColor;
```

`Universal` is an [attached object](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#attached-properties-and-attached-signal-handlers), you can attach it to an abitrary object, not just the current one, by doing `<object>.<AttachingType>`.
We attach it to the parent window by accessing the window via another attached property: [`Window.window`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-window.html#window-attached-prop).

Comment: When I used that inside the external JS function I got ```ReferenceError: Window is not defined``` and after adding ```.import QtQuick.Window 2.14 as Window```:```TypeError: Cannot read property 'Universal' of undefined```.